# Python 3, split the current single file source code in one main file and multiple sub-files. Do I need to import common modules in all files?

Tags: python, import, split, global

I have a main.py file that includes a number of functions, classes as well as global variables (some of which are used as constants while others are used as global variables).

(I know that as a rule the use of global variables is not a good practice but in my case there is no hazard).

Additionally, the main.py imports a number of modules that are used either by the main.py (main function within it), or/and by the functions and classes within the main.py.

So, I'd like to split the code into more .py files, for example move the "assistant" functions in a separate file e.g. assistantFuncts.py.

Now, both main.py and assistantFuncts.py may use common modules, e.g. smtplib, and share common global variables

In the above case, do I have to import smtplib in both .py files?
Additionally, do I need to declare as global the shared variables used by both files, in both files? And how about the initialization of the variables?

I expected that importing and declaring them in the main.py would be enough, but it seems that it is not...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import modules that are used in both the main code and a module correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485901/how-to-import-modules-that-are-used-in-both-the-main-code-and-a-module-correctly)

Comment: Partly yes. I'm just trying to figure out how to use import in the same manner as include is used in PHP...